# even after apply all the rules of .env file in vite-react such REACT_APP_ , root directory, restart, process.env ,still getting process is not defined

Tags: reactjs, sanity, .env

**.env in root-**
`REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID= //project id REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN= //project token`

**client.js in src-**

```
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = sanityClient({
 projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
 dataset: "production",
 apiVersion: "2023-01-01",
 useCdn: true,
 token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) = builder.image(source);
```

**about.jsx--**
i was trying to fetch about data from sanity

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the .env file in /src directory